# Tensorflow ExponentialMovingAverage with PartitionedVariable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage` with a `PartitionedVariable`.

I use a `custom_getter` to create an EMA version of the graph.

If I don't use a `partitioner` to create my variable the following code works as expected : after setting the variable to zero, with a decay of 1, the EMA version of this variable keeps the original value.

However, if I use a partitioner, I have the following issues

**tf1.12** the `ema_getter` is unable to find the average of the `PartitionedVariable` hence the two variables are the same object

**tf.1.15** I get an `AttributeError: 'PartitionedVariable' object has no attribute 'experimental_ref'`

Here is my code

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def ema_getter(ema):
    def _ema_getter(getter, name, *args, **kwargs):
        var = getter(name, *args, **kwargs)
        ema_var = ema.average(var)
        if not ema_var:
            tf.logging.warning(f"Unable to find EMA of {name}")
        return ema_var if ema_var else var

    return _ema_getter


if __name__ == "__main__":
    use_partitioner = True
    var = tf.get_variable(
        name='var',
        shape=[10, 2],
        initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),
        partitioner=tf.fixed_size_partitioner(2, axis=0) if use_partitioner else None
    )
    var_sum = tf.reduce_sum(var)
    ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(1.0)
    variables = tf.get_collection(
        tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, tf.get_variable_scope().name)
    ema_op = ema.apply(variables)

    with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True, custom_getter=ema_getter(ema)):
        var_ema = tf.get_variable(
            name='var',
            shape=[10, 2],
            partitioner=tf.fixed_size_partitioner(2, axis=0) if use_partitioner else None
        )
        print(f"EMA variable name: {var_ema.name}")
        var_ema_sum = tf.reduce_sum(var_ema)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(ema_op)
        print(sess.run(var_sum))  # 20.0
        print(sess.run(var_ema_sum))  # 20.0
        sess.run(tf.assign(var, tf.zeros_like(var)))
        sess.run(ema_op)
        print(sess.run(var_sum))  # 0.0
        print(sess.run(var_ema_sum))  # should be 20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding so far is that the `PartitionedVariable` does not act as a standard `Variable` but is merely a shell for a list of other `Variable`.

The `custom_getter` needs to take this into account and manually retrieve and reconstruct a `ParitionedVariable` using the ema versions of the original `PartitionedVariable` variables.

However, this seems hacky -- using a `.__class__` because I could not find a way to import `PartitionedVariable` in a clean way, or accessing the private attribute `_partitions` for ex.

Sharing my current fix here

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def ema_getter(ema):
    def _ema_getter(getter, name, *args, **kwargs):
        var = getter(name, *args, **kwargs)
        # Manually reconstruct if PartitionedVariable
        if var.__class__.__name__ == "PartitionedVariable":
            ema_vs = [ema.average(v) for v in var]
            ema_var = var.__class__(
                name=var.name,
                shape=var.shape,
                dtype=var.dtype,
                variable_list=ema_vs,
                partitions=var._partitions,
            )
        else:
            ema_var = ema.average(var)

        if not ema_var:
            tf.logging.warning(f"Unable to find EMA of {name}")

        return ema_var if ema_var else var

    return _ema_getter


if __name__ == "__main__":
    use_partitioner = True
    var = tf.get_variable(
        name='var',
        shape=[10, 2],
        initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),
        partitioner=tf.fixed_size_partitioner(2, axis=0) if use_partitioner else None
    )
    var_sum = tf.reduce_sum(var)
    ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(1.0)
    variables = tf.get_collection(
        tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, tf.get_variable_scope().name)
    ema_op = ema.apply(variables)

    with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True, custom_getter=ema_getter(ema)):
        var_ema = tf.get_variable(
            name='var',
            shape=[10, 2],
            partitioner=tf.fixed_size_partitioner(2, axis=0) if use_partitioner else None
        )
        print(f"EMA variable name: {var_ema.name}")
        var_ema_sum = tf.reduce_sum(var_ema)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(ema_op)
        print(sess.run(var_sum))
        print(sess.run(var_ema_sum))
        sess.run(tf.assign(var, tf.zeros_like(var)))
        sess.run(ema_op)
        print(sess.run(var_sum))
        print(sess.run(var_ema_sum))
```